# creating table with indexes for rows mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to create a table in MySQL that will have indexes for each row , and when I  insert records they will be inserted at the tail of the table.
And I will be able to make queries by row numbers.

Can you give me an example how to do so ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: are you trying to create in c# or in mysql only

Comment: @ Ibu , I will run it in my c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `symbols` ( 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
    `animal` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', 
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) 
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Read more on [mysql here](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)